# How do I embed Street View image so it shows view from a street (not from inside of building)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

On my website I am showing location of some points of interest. Next to the map I am showing Street View image which purpose is to show how this place looks from outside (so for example one could find more easily in which building place is located). But recently I've noticed that for some shops there is a "street view" from inside of buildings. I don't want to show such images, is there a way to make Street View only show street view?

Answer (score 1):

I've searched thru api-issues and it seems such feature is requested but not implemented yet. You can see it here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4831

Comment: Yup. I think you are right. Subscribe to the issue if not done yet as the more subscribers the best chances it has to be implemented. Good point though.